# SWIFT - Why Horizontal Scroll View and Feature does not work

Tags: swift, scroll, view, paging

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq71SPkJIus but for some reason nothing is appearing in the simulator and there are no errors, it just says "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1", is that an error? Sorry I'm pretty new to this and not really sure

I checked all the code to make sure it is right and it is so not sure what to do, or what I did wrong

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var slideScrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slideScrollView.delegate = self
        let slides:[Slide] = createSlides() //THREAD 1: BREAKPOINT 1.1
        setupScrollView(slides: slides)
        pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func createSlides() -> [Slide] {
        let slide1:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide1.label.text = "Slide1"

        let slide2:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide2.label.text = "Slide2"

        return [slide1, slide2]
    }

    func setupScrollView(slides:[Slide]) {
        slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width)
        slideScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
        slideScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            slideScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are seeing?

[image: breakpoint]

If that's the case, you just enabled a breakpoint in some part of your code.

just tap this to disable it

[image]

If you are new to development, just look for tutorials on how to debug code on Xcode or any other IDE to get the grasp of it, you will learn a lot of cool stuff that's taken as obvious, but it really isn't. Those things will help you out your path of becoming a great developer. Good Luck!

and click play to continue
[image]